# Google+ Games API java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, google-plus, runtimeexception

Hi I whant to build the Google+ Games API in my Game that I am developing. But I have the problem that I can't send scores directly to the API because the Game dosen't run in an Activity. So I whant to send the score to a function in an external class so I tried this code:

```
private void updateGameOver(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);          

                    Leaboarder lea = new Leaboarder();
                    lea.sendScore(Counter.getScore());

                    nullify();
                    game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
                    return;
            }
        }

    }
```

But I get the following error:

```
06-27 21:58:30.746: W/dalvikvm(5701): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b88300)
06-27 21:58:30.756: E/AndroidRuntime(5701): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-46367
06-27 21:58:30.756: E/AndroidRuntime(5701): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
06-27 21:58:30.756: E/AndroidRuntime(5701):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
06-27 21:58:30.756: E/AndroidRuntime(5701):     at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:749)
06-27 21:58:30.756: E/AndroidRuntime(5701):     at de.niklaskellner.flydroid.gui.GoogleGame.Leaboarder.<init>(Leaboarder.java:20)
06-27 21:58:30.756: E/AndroidRuntime(5701):     at de.niklaskellner.flydroid.GameScreen.updateGameOver(GameScreen.java:174)
06-27 21:58:30.756: E/AndroidRuntime(5701):     at de.niklaskellner.flydroid.GameScreen.update(GameScreen.java:80)
06-27 21:58:30.756: E/AndroidRuntime(5701):     at de.niklaskellner.framework.implementation.AndroidFastRenderView.run(AndroidFastRenderView.java:47)
06-27 21:58:30.756: E/AndroidRuntime(5701):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

My Leaboarder class:

```
public class Leaboarder extends Activity implements GameHelper.GameHelperListener {

    protected GameHelper mHelper;
    protected int mRequestedClients = GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES;
    public static int score = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int score = getIntent().getIntExtra("score", 0);
        sendScore(score);
    }

    public void sendScore(int score) {

                        mHelper = new GameHelper(Leaboarder.this);
                        mHelper.setup(Leaboarder.this, mRequestedClients);

                        GamesClient mGamesClient = mHelper.getGamesClient();
                        if (mHelper.isSignedIn()) {         

                            mGamesClient.submitScore("", score);
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Loggin - Score saved offline.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("offlineScore", 0);
                            int scoreOLD = pref.getInt("topscore", 0);
                            if (score > scoreOLD){
                                pref.edit().putInt("topscore", score).apply();
                            }
                        }




    }
}
```

My Question is how can I work around that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just call `Looper.prepare();` as second statement in your `onCreate` method.